# Rational equivalence and infinitesimal deformation of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, hilbert-schemes

Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two rationally equivalent curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Is it true that the dimension of $H^0(\mathcal{N}_{C_1|\mathbb{P}^3})$ equal to that of $H^0(\mathcal{N}_{C_2|\mathbb{P}^3})$?

Comment: No, that is not true.  Even if $C_1$ and $C_2$ have the  same Hilbert polynomial, which is stronger than being rationally equivalent in $\mathbb{P}^3$, that is not true.  Even if the two curves are parameterized by points in the same irreducible component of the Hilbert scheme, that is not true. Let $C_1$ be a twisted cubic, and let $C_2$ be a specialization of a twisted cubic whose reduced curve is a planar, nodal cubic, but with a spatial embedded point at the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, even if you assume $C_1$ and $C_2$ smooth irreducible. A rational equivalence class of curves in $\Bbb{P}^3$ is determined by its degree. Take for $C_1$ a complete intersection of 2 quadrics, you get 
$\dim H^0(\mathcal{N}_{C_1|\mathbb{P}^3})= 16$; and for $C_2$ a plane quartic curve, you find $\dim H^0(\mathcal{N}_{C_2|\mathbb{P}^3})= 17$.